# Having trouble working with subtypes in MySQL

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, subtype

I'm having some trouble with using subtypes/supertypes in MySQL.

I use C# .NET to make an administration system for my local club, and I have some trouble making a nice database.

My database looks like this:

supertype:

```
========
Product
---------
Prod_id (PK)
Name
Barcode
```

and the subtype:

```
=======
Card
--------
Prod_id (FK)
Price
```

I have 3 subtypes, `Cards`, `Weapons`, `Ammunition` which are basically the same thing (though I store different things in them).

Maybe I'm overcomplicating things, but all I want to do is, when I create a new card, that a product is automatically generated (I use a trigger for that), and that the `Cards.Prod_id` gets set to the newly generated `Product.Prod_Id`.

How do I do this?

Is this the right way of using subtypes, or am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use trigger. But, there is another, I think better way:

- Alter *Product* table - add **AUTO_INCREMENT** property to the primary key.
- Insert new product, MySQL will generate new ID
- Get last inserted ID using **last_insert_id** MySQL function, and insert new record in child table

MySQL example:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
Prod_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(40),
Barcode INT
);

CREATE TABLE Card(
Prod_id INT,
Price DECIMAL(8, 2),
FOREIGN KEY (Prod_id) REFERENCES Product(Prod_id)
);

INSERT INTO Product VALUES (NULL, 'phone', 1000);
INSERT INTO Card VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 10.5);
```

First INSERT wall add new product with autogenerated ID. The second, will get this new ID and use it for new Card record.

[Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Also `(Prod_id)` will be not only an FK but the PK in `Card` (and in `Weapons` and in `Ammonution`). So you don't have 2 cards with same `Prod__id`, not even by accident.